# page break is not working in print preview

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, page-break

```
div.pagebreak {
 page-break-after: always;
 page-break-inside: avoid; 
}
```

HTML

```
 <!-- Page separator -->
  <div class="pagebreak" style="float: none;"><hr class="hidden-print" /></div>
  <app-mud-check-header [report] ="mudCheckWorksheet"></app-mud-check-header>
```

Above is the code to add the page Breaker, however it does not seem to work, everything gets printed on one page .I have tried using
break-after , break-inside as well, not working
Please suggest.

Comment: I can't be sure anyway as stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after .. _"it was replaced by the break-after property."_ maybe try with that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-after .. anyway it will also depend on which env you are using to print that html (from browser? which version..)

Comment: I am using Chrome

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, there're some cases where page break won't work if the tag or the parent tag has a certain properties.

1. using page-break inside tables
2. floating elements
3. inline-block elements
4. block elements with borders.

Answer (score 0):

The page-break-after and page-break-inside CSS properties can be used to specify how page breaks should be inserted in an HTML document when printing. However, the page-break-after property only works when applied to block-level elements, such as div elements, and will not work when applied to inline elements such as text.

To fix the issue, you can try applying the page-break-after property to a block-level element that is a parent of the div element with the pagebreak class.

```
div.pagebreak {
  page-break-after: always;
  page-break-inside: avoid; 
}

.parent {
  page-break-after: always;
}

<div class="parent">
  <div class="pagebreak">
    <app-mud-check-header [report] ="mudCheckWorksheet"></app-mud-check-header>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this , but still it is not working.I am using chrome browser

Comment: I understood the issue ,under my.html i have a div with fullscreen class 
.fullScreen {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9000;
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
} the position is causing the issue of not breaking the page in preview, what can be the work around to handle this